# Azure ADF V2: Passing pipeline parameter of type array to Azure function which triggers Snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

Our current migration project from Azure Sql to Snowflake is using ADF V2 as orchestration tool. We need to call snowflake procedures through ADF pipeline which is parametrized (Ex: Pipeline has an array as parameter with list of tables and statements to be passed to ADF activities within the pipeline). Since ADF stored procedure activity is not supporting Snowflake procedure call, we have a work around to use Azure Function to call Snowflake sql statements and we were able create one and used that in ADF pipeline to call procedure. This procedure has to be re-used dynamically by accepting table name from pipeline parameter which is an array containing all table names along with other fields.

But, we were facing difficulty to figure out passing ADF pipeline array parameters to Azure function procedure call, not sure this is the limitation of azure function in ADF V2.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if we have a parameter called "ListTables" then We can use below syntax expression to take value from your pipeline parameter.
@{pipeline().parameters.ListTables}
If you are using Azure Function which will be triggered using HTTP request, then inside your request body you many need to pass above parameter with same mentioned syntax. Thank you.
In below example, I am trying call Azure Function which is triggered using HTTP request and I am passing my "ListTables" array in to request body.
[image]